# How do I render something out with sound

Tags: animation

I am a beginner and i made a simple key frame animation and i added sound in the video editing part of blender. My only challenge is to figure out how render it out open it file explorer and be able to watch and listen to the animation. i will my blend file below the question

Comment: BLENDER FILE:   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=NWyryq5W" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/NWyryq5W/)

Comment: on the top left > Render > Render Animation, make sure that the destination folder is correct in the Properties panel > Output > Output

Comment: thanks but that did not do anything

Comment: Sorry I can't test as I can't see any file within your file, I'm not sure you can pack movies or sounds in the VSE...

Comment: If u go to layout the animation is working but u cant see it in video editing